# Indexing and filtering in Elasticssearch using the NEST (HighLevelClient) without using POCO objects

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, indexing, filtering, nest

I'm using the ElasticHighLevelClient (NEST) to index data from SQL DB storage. The problem is that I don't have access to the POCO objects and that I have to filter over this data. POCO objects have nested fields, for example

```
class Car{
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Model { get; set; }
public List<Engine> Engines { get; set; }
public List<Wheel> Wheels {get; set;}
}


class Engine {
public string Id { get; set; }
public string EngineModel { get; set; }
public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }
public List<Maker> Makers { get; set; }
}

class Wheel {
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
} 

class Maker {
public string Id { get; set; }
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

I found this question [Bulk Indexing in Elasticssearch using the ElasticLowLevelClient client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754597/bulk-indexing-in-elasticssearch-using-the-elasticlowlevelclient-client) but i have several problems with it: **'PostData.PostData(string) is inaccessible due to its protection level.** I changed it to **new PostData.Serializable(stringJson))**; but i've got "**cannot resolve symbol 'Serializible'**" error.

So, can anybody help me with next moments:

1) How can I index Car object without having access to the POCO objects?

2) How can I setup filtering with nested objects for example all cars that have an Engine.Type = “petrol” and Engine.Maker = “ltd”?

Thanks!